# jQuery validate() not working when user previously filled out form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

After much struggling with it, I finally got my jQuery validate() to do what I wanted it to do.

With one exception. I saw someone else with this problem, but now I can't find that page, so I'm forced to ask again.

Let's use "First Name" as my field in question. It's required, so, if I tab past it, or submit with it blank, I execute the code (which in this case, adds the `invalid` class to the element) and all works well.

If I type in my name, it successfully applies the `valid` class.

However, if I start to type in my name, and after I type "D", it shows me a previously entered value (as forms are wont to do) and I select it, something strange happens.

The style of the input field goes away. It doesn't show the valid or invalid class being applied. Actually it doesn't even show the CSS that I put on blank fields.

If I submit, it comes across as valid but still no style change unless I literally type something else in that field.

This is true across all fields in my form.

EDIT: Adding jquery code

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    onkeyup: function (valueToBeTested) {
        if($(valueToBeTested).hasClass('required')){
            if($(valueToBeTested).valid()){
                $(valueToBeTested).removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            } else{
                $(valueToBeTested).removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            };
        };
    },
    onfocusout: function (valueToBeTested) {
        if($(valueToBeTested).hasClass('required')){
            if($(valueToBeTested).valid()){
                $(valueToBeTested).removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            } else{
                $(valueToBeTested).removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            };
        };
    },
    rules:
        {
       ....(rules)
    }
});
```

Like I said, it even acknowledges on the submit that the field value is valid. It just ignores the `onkeyup` and `onfocusout` until I type another character if I chose the value from an auto suggest dropdown.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: um, @Sparky, this is very much not the same question. I know since I'm the one who asked that other one. Please read both again and you'll see. Thanks.

Comment: Both problems caused by the same root issue- you're overriding the default callbacks with unneeded and superfluous code that's breaking the default functionality.